# Pinch zoom in NetworkImageView loading using Volley in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley, pinchzoom, networkimageview

Is there a way to include pinch zoom feature on NetworkImageView while using Volley in Android Studio ?

I have successfully loaded images from url using volley and networkimageview. I want to be able to add pinch zoom feature or zoom-in and zoom-out feature in the Networkimageview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use custom image view that mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37652795/11670453) or just by using [picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/) library you can add pinch zoom.

Comment: Can I get a code of working example please ?
I had tried using the above mentioned link. Both the given classes i.e., TouchImageView and customNetworkImageView were created successfully. But xml layout is showing error when I add customnetworkimageview in the layout.

Comment: The code mentioned above i.e., https://gist.github.com/vkrm26/a21b5cca5d928485c4bc910a835e0003 is working just fine. Thankyou!
Just a small change, in xml layout inplace of <CustomNetworkImageView we need to write <com.example.CustomNetworkImageView